# Chrome extension that reloads the webpage until a particular condition is met (example: HTML contains "hello")

Tags: web-development, chrome, automation, artificial-intelligence, scripting

- I often need to troubleshoot rare bugs in webpages.
- To trigger a rare bug, I typically need to refresh the webpage 100 or 1000 times until the bug appears (for instance an error message is shown, or an HTML element is missing).

Is there a Chrome extension or TamperMonkey/etc script that can automate this tedious task?
Obviously, it must stop when the condition is met.

*Simple conditions (HTML contains or does not contain a given string) are enough. I can get my hands dirty modifying scripts if needed. Bonus if more elaborate conditions are available, for instance checking HTTP Response statuses, or checking whether a video is playing, or even asking to an AI a question about the page's HTML or screenshot or screencast.*

Answer (score 0):

Bunch of various ways to do it, but I'd recommend [Automa](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/automa/infppggnoaenmfagbfknfkancpbljcca) as potentially the easiest one.

You can use blocks like:

- Delay with While Loop/Repeat Task or anything alike
- Reload Tab
- Element Exists, Get Text + Conditions, ...

etc. to build the automation flow in a matter of minutes. Then you can duplicate and reuse the flow for various use cases.

It works for website testing, auto clicking, auto form filling and anything else that can be done with JS.